# Input Commas into regex during the whole number part of 10,4 decimal

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex that will limit a decimal to 10,4 but in the whole number part (10) I would like it to separate with commas.

For example - 1,123,123,123.1234

This gets me close to what I need - \d{0,10}.\d{4}
But I would like to show commas as in the example.

But I am not sure how to tweak this to achieve what I need?

Comment: are you sure that  123,123,123,1.1234 is what you want, I'd have expected output along the lines of 1,231,231,231.1234

Comment: @JGNI You are correct, I will edit

Comment: Can you clarify whether numbers without 4 floating digits should be matched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the following :

```
(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3}){0,2}|\d(?:,\d{3}){3}|\d{1,10})(?:\.\d{1,4})?
```

I've tested it [here](https://regex101.com/r/RBBzBO/2).

The whole pattern is an integer part followed by an optional floating part.

The integer part, `(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3}){0,2}|\d(?:,\d{3}){3}|\d{1,10})`, is an alternative between three sub-patterns :

- up to 9 digits with commas, `\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3}){0,2}`, which is a leading group of digits of one to three digits followed by up to two optional groups of exactly three digits, groups which are separated by commas
- the 10 digits case with commas, `\d(?:,\d{3}){3}`, in which the leading digits group must contain exactly one digit and is followed by three three-digits groups, groups which are separated by commas
- the commas-less number you had to begin with, `\d{1,10}`

The floating part is a dot followed by at least one digit and at most four.

Note that if you can avoid using a regex you absolutely should, this is the kind of regex which will make maintainers cry...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with a single regex

The algorithm I use is

1. Take the part of the number before the decimal point
2. Convert that to a string
3. Reverse the string
4. Split the string into chunks of 3 digits allowing the last group to have 1, 2 or 3 digits (this depends on your programming language)
5. Join the string together inserting `,` **between** each group
6. Reverse the string.
7. Concatenate a decimal point and the decimal digits if necessary.

You now have a correctly formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

The following perl code uses a trick to work from right to left:

```
$num = 12345678.01;
$rev = reverse($num);
$rev =~ s/(\d{3})(?=\d)(?!\d*\.)/$1,/g;
$res = reverse($rev);
print "$res\n";
```

results in

```
12,345,678.01
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the job:

```
^(?:\d,)?\d{0,3}(?:,\d{1,3}){0,2}\.\d{4}$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of string
  (?:\d,)?          # non capture group, a digit and a comma, optional
  \d{0,3}           # 0 to 3 digits
  (?:               # non capture group
    ,               # a comma
    \d{1,3}         # a to 3 digits
  ){0,2}            # end group, may appear 0, 1 or 2 times
  \.                # a dot
  \d{4}             # 4 digits
$                   # end of string
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/V3LOuo/1)